# Dividing a line in to equal segments and calculating straightness of segments

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I have an arc as shown in the picture. If i need to divide the arc to equal segments and calculate the straightness of each segment, how should i proceed? Any input will be appreciated.

I was planning to calculate Straightness as Arc-length / Straight line distance between end points

[Sample arc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVQt4.jpg)

Comment: This is called [Sinuosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity)

Comment: @DanielMathias Can i calculate the arc-length using distance formulae?